# Java extends access to method

Tags: java, extends

I create a simple code to understand and solve my problem,
i create a class Animal and a class Dog witch extend the Animal class.
i want to accese the method getFoots() of the class Dog
I have an error at the System.out.println(animal1.getFoots()); Undeclared method
I create o object Dog and an object Animal i set Animal = Dog and after what i want to access i variable tha is at Dog class
What should i change in the  System.out.println() line ?

```
public class Animal{
    private String name;
    
    public Animal(){
        name = "NoName";
    }
    
    public String getName(){    
        return name;
    }

}


public class Dog extends Animal{    
    private int foots;
    
    public Dog(int foots){
        this.foots=foots;
    }
    
    public int getFoots(){    //method i want to access
        return foots;
    }
    
}


public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dog dog1 = new Dog(4); 
        Animal  animal1;
        animal1 = dog1;
        System.out.println(animal1.getName());
        System.out.println(animal1.getFoots());    //her i have the error Undeclared method
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using `instanceof` with casting can solve this in a simple fashion, but it is generally discouraged to do this as it breaks or at least bends OOP principles and leads to brittle code. Better to declare needed method signatures in the parent class. Another option is to gain "double-dispatch" like abilities using a visitor design pattern.